# Declaring function prototypes locally in other functions in C

Tags: c

What is the point of making nested function? This happens in the book of K&R "The C Programming Language" sometimes, e.g. on page 110 they declare a swap function in the qsort:

```c
void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right)
{
   int i, last;
   void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);
   etc.
```

Is this only a matter of style or is there a more crucial aspect behind it?

Comment: namespace & validity

Comment: My 5 cents - I have *never* seen anyone doing it in any production code for my whole decades-long C experience.

Comment: A lot of K&R follows the spirit of "lets do stupid things just because we can". I wouldn't recommend using that book for learning.

Comment: Ostensibly it's to limit the visibility of `swap` to `qsort`.  In reality it's a pretty useless practice.  Life is just easier if you define called functions before their callers (if both are in the same source file) - that way you don't need to maintain a separate declaration at all.  I don't do it, and in 30 years I haven't seen anyone else do it outside of a textbook.  It just really doesn't make sense in real code.

Comment: It would be great, if you could *define* a function inside another one, so explicitly disallowing every other use of it apart from the function itself. Declaring them doesn't seem equally useful to me.

Comment: Speculation: on an early compiler it might have saved memory in the compilation process, since the compiler could forget about the declaration of `swap` after it was done compiling `qsort`.  Otherwise it doesn't accomplish much.  Because of C's one definition rule, having `swap` defined elsewhere in the program means that it already pollutes the global namespace, so nothing is lost by having the declaration at global scope.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: [gcc added that as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

Comment: @Lundin What reference book would you recommend then?

Comment: "Let's do stupid stuff because we can" is perhaps the least accurate characterization of K&R that I have ever seen.  Parts of that book are dated, it's true, but there's also a huge amount of sage, understated wisdom there.  (But this is of course not the place for a debate on that, and if someone wishes to argue the contrary opinion, I will let you have the last word; I will not post further in this thread.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. It's extremely close to having lambda functions in this way. In the description, they also state that the implementation is done with *trampolines* (which I understand are closures).

Comment: Definitely a matter of style, I'd say; nothing more behind it.

Comment: @SteveSummit It's hard to find a single well-written code example in the book - you can give me pretty much any code example from the book and I'll show you problems. Starting with `main() { printf("hello, world\n"); }` which has never been correct after 1989. A function with a return value but no `return` statement invokes undefined behavior if the caller (OS) uses that value. Omitting `return` from main() was fixed in C99, but then you are no longer allowed to write `main()` with implicit `int`.  The 2nd edition was never fully updated to standard C89, the attempt to do so was sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

It limits the visibility of the declared function to that function.

For example, if we have a file `hw.c` which contains

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printHelloWorld()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

and a file `main.c` which contains

```
void func()
{
    // printHelloWorld(); // Incorrect, function is not visible here.
}

int main()
{
    void printHelloWorld();
    printHelloWorld();

    func();
}
```

then the function `printHelloWorld` is only visible to the `main` function for that file.

A similar, although less useful, application is when the two functions are in the same file. Let's say `main` is defined first (as above) and `printHelloWorld` is defined below it. Then `printHelloWorld` will be visible from it definition downwards, with the exception of it also being visible in `main`.

That said, this method of declaring functions is rare and I would not call it idiomatic C.

Comment: @Student I'm sure they could, but for whatever reason chose not to do so here. To be fair to K&R, the first edition came out in 1978 and the second edition in 1988. This was before a lot of (publicly visible) C was written, so what is not considered idiomatic now may have been OK back then.

Comment: @Student: It's as much an artifact of writing code for a textbook as anything else - there's not a whole lot of real estate on a printed page, so some examples are a little dodgy in the name of saving space.  It may also be a function of wanting to get a specific concept across, not necessarily the most idiomatic way to write it.  And finally, what constitutes "idiomatic" C code has changed a lot since K&R was written.

Comment: I used to occasionally declare external functions locally.  I don't any more.  I don't think it's a big deal either way.  And, yes, the consensus on various facets of "idiomatic C code" has shifted quite a bit over the years.

Comment: @Student Most of the examples from the book were written in the mid 1970s before idiomatic C and good programming practices in general were invented. So they couldn't write idiomatic C because it was yet to be invented. In the 1980s, K&R itself was regarded as idiomatic since there was literally nothing else to compare with. What later became idiomatic didn't settle until after standardization in 1989, after a lot of the code in K&R got obsolete. And then with the 2nd revision of C in 1999, what was idiomatic changed in many places.